# python selenium webdriver scraping each page

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm scraping content from each page by clicking the next page in a while loop. Unfortunately, I can't give the URL as it is a restricted site.

Here is the relevant piece of my script with a long brittle xpath;

```
        html1 = browser.page_source
        df1 = pd.read_html(html1, header=None)
        for df in df1:
            with open("pages.csv", "a") as f:
                df.to_csv(f, header=None, lineterminator='\n')
                browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/dashboard-grid/ul/li/dashboard-panel/div/doc-table/div/paginate/paginate-controls[1]/div/ul/li[7]/a").click()
```

Here is the HTML

```
<a ng-click="paginate.goToPage(page.next)">»</a>
```

The li[7] nth child will not always be correct as the number of pages change.
I can't seem to figure out a way to get an xpath contains statement to work either.
I've also tried custom xpath statements such as browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[text()='>>']").click() with no luck.

Comment: `browser.find_element_by_link_text("»").click()`

Comment: Thanks n1c9 that was too obvious I'm not sure how I missed it, works perfectly!

Comment: :-) glad to hear it!